# Number from NSDictionary

Tags: ios

This is the code I'm using to pull a number from a dictionary,

```
int num = [[sharedManager.data objectForKey:@"sum(units.num)"]intValue];
```

This is the key/value of the number which is printed in the debugger.

```
key = (__NSCFString *)  @"sum(units.num)"   0x176d4d40
value = (__NSCFNumber *) (long)38244    0x176ca850
```

And this is the result I'm getting,

```
num = (int) 393051808
```

What i need is for num to be 38244.

Does anyone know why I'm getting this result?

Thanks
Paul.

Comment: The code you posted has no variable "key" nor "value". Post the actual complete code. You _know_ that something that you think is right is indeed wrong, so don't hide it.

Comment: out of curiosity what happens if you do?
NSInteger num = [[sharedManager.data objectForKey:@"sum(units.num)"]integerValue]; ?

Comment: lead_the_zeppelin I've tried that i get num = 0

Comment: @gnasher729: key = .../value = … is displayed in the Xcode Debug Variables view for dictionaries, or printed by "Quick Look" to the console.

Comment: @Paulie: Split your statement in separate steps: `NSDictionary *dict =  [sharedManager.data]; NSNumber *val = dict[@"sum(units.num)"]; int num = [val intValue];` - Check the class of each variable and check if it contains what you expect.

Comment: when i split it the results i get are, val = (long)38244, num = 668570276

Comment: did you try `int num = [[sharedManager.data valueForKey:@"sum(units.num)"]intValue];` (valueForKey instead of objectForKey)

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx yes i get num = 0

Comment: I'm betting that a big part of your problem is simply trusting the Xcode debugger to display data correctly -- it often doesn't, especially if you are careless about where you're stopped.  To display a value, in the Xcode console window type `p someScalarVariable` or `po somePointerVariable`.  Or use NSLog.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you are getting is , the integer representation (`393051808`)  of your `key`'s memory address (0x176d4d40).

Do this,

```
NSNumber *number = [sharedManager.data objectForKey:@"sum(units.num)"];

int num = [number intValue];
```

// or

```
long num = [number longValue]; //because your number is a long value
```

Comment: When doing this i get number = (long)38244, but num = (long)16

Comment: this is what the op has

Comment: @Daij-Djan actually no.

Comment: @Paulie - longValue had nothing to do with it.  There was something else wrong with your code.

Comment: @sleepwalkerfx please explain then what the difference is. sorry Im too blind to see it

Comment: your two lines are one line in the question but that hardly matters ;) .. just actually no isnt a cool answer